# Is there any framework to automate UI of a website other than Galen framework

Tags: selenium, automation, continuous-integration, galen

I am currently working on TestNG framework in which Galen framework is embedded. The Galen Testcases deals the UI part of our website.

I have researched a lot and there is no other automation tools same or better than that of Galen Framework for UI testing specifically.

I am well aware that it can be done with coding Java or even writing testcases script manually in Java itself. But, is there any other advanced UI automation too available in market?

I want this because the report of Galen is such a big size that mailing this report or moving this report is not a good practice(Which makes my CI/CD pipeline slow).

Comment: Have you considered using [puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer)? I don't know what specifically you want to test in the UI, but it might be useful.

Comment: are you trying to automate layout testing or functionality testing?

Comment: Layout testing is what I meant as UI testing